# Halloumi at room temperature

Tags: food-safety, cheese, refrigerator

I recently ordered a batch of halloumi cheese online. It was packaged as fist-sized, vacuum-sealed pieces with a little liquid in each (brine I guess). It is supposed to be refrigerated, and the package had a gel pack for cooling. Unfortunately, the package was delayed by over a week, as the postal carrier mixed up. So I will have to assume that the halloumi has been sitting at room temperature for over a week.

Should I be concerned about any food safety issues here (botulism etc.)? Especially anything that does not go away by grilling/frying?

EDIT: I am aware of the two-hour rule etc., but that rule would already be violated if the package had arrived on time, as I cannot imagine that a little gel pack would keep temperatures in the safe zone for two days in a cardboard box sent halfway across the country (no special isolation or anything). I am really asking about the specifics of this particular food item.

Comment: To your edit: There are no specifics. Food safety rules are designed to be unambigious. You can either prove that your cheese meets the 2-hour rule, or it is unsafe. There is nothing more to it - on purpose.

Comment: So you are saying the vendor already violated food safety rules?